# Can't get Distinct method to work on LINQ query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq

I'm working on an MVC application that at this point should return Distinct users who have made an entry in the SQL table.  I have a column in the Table called EnteredBy that contains names off all users (about 10 different users) who have made entry multiple times.  I have tried this LINQ query but it is not working:

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult DisplayCount()
{

        var enteredBy = (from user in db.Table
                         select user.EnteredBy).Distinct();


        ViewBag.Count = enteredBy.Count();

        return View(enteredBy);
}
```

I also tried this as suggested by someone else:

```
[HandleError]
public ActionResult DisplayCount()
{

        var enteredBy = (from user in db.Table
                        select new { user.EnteredBy}).Distinct();


        ViewBag.Count = enteredBy.Count();

        return View(enteredBy);
}
```

View:

```
@model  IEnumerable<Statistic.Models.Table>

@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <title>DisplayCount</title>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    Entered by: <br /><br />

    @foreach (var m in Model)
    {

        @m.EnteredBy <br />

    }

    <br /> Total Count: <br />
    @ViewBag.Count
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

But it yields the same result:

> An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Is there something I'm missing?

Stack Trace:

```
[InvalidOperationException: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[<>f__AnonymousType4`1[System.String]]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Statistic.Models.DashboardLibAnswer]'.]
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary`1.SetModel(Object value) +175
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewDataDictionary..ctor(ViewDataDictionary dictionary) +361
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage`1.SetViewData(ViewDataDictionary viewData) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +98
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +107
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +291
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +245
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +22
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +176
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +75
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +99
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +50
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +39
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +29
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +55
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +31
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629296
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Added an answer - looks like you have the wrong model type for your view.

Comment: I've added View as well

Comment: Nick - the model you specify in the view is completely different from what your controller is returning to the view. Look at my answer

Comment: I don't just need the count, I also need to return the list of all distinct users.  Count is just something extra I added to make sure the query is running correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are doing this:

```
return View(enteredBy);
```

It appears that your view page does not expect this type of model.

If you are storing the number of users in ViewBag, then you don't need to pass the query to the model:

```
ViewBag.Count = enteredBy.Count();

return View(); // dont need a strongly typed model
```

Then in your view you can display it like so:

```
User Count: @ViewBag.Count
```

If you look at your view (DisplayCount.cshtml), you should check what you have for your @model statement. If you're using ViewBag, you don't even need it. If you want to switch to a strongly typed model, you could use int instead, since that's all you really want at this point is a count of users:

```
@model int

User Count: @Model
```

**edit**

Looks like you are trying to get the list of users, not a count of users. Try this:

```
var uniqueUsers = db.Table.Select(t => t.EnteredBy).Distinct().ToList();

return View(uniqueUsers);
```

Your view will need an IEnumerable:

```
@model IEnumerable<string>

@foreach(var user in Model)
{
    Entered By: @user
}
```

Comment: I've tried this but now it throws "System.NullReferenceException" at @foreach (var m in Model)

Comment: Updated, wasn't quite sure what you were asking but I think this is what you want.

Comment: Awesome Dismissile, 2nd edit worked.  Can you explain a little what exactly was done differently there.  Thanks again for solving this!

Comment: @Nick Basically you want a list of user names. You only really care about the names (not the full Table entity) so the query basically does a projection to return just the usernames (Select) and does a distinct on that to get rid of duplicates. This data is getting passed to the view as a collection of strings (IEnumerable<string>) instead of the full entity.

Answer (score 1):

Nick, what is in your stack trace? The error message seems to indicate that you'll get more information from the inner exception, why not check it out?

Another workaround would be to call `.ToList().Distinct` in your second example. This will pull the data out of the db and then do the count for you on your side of the wire, so it's maybe not what you need from a perf standpoint, but it should work.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you wanna get one Table entity for each different EnteredBy...

The model of your view is an `IEnumerable<Statistic.Models.DashboardLibAnswer>`.

You pass a strange Queryable of anonymous string...

so your query should be something like that (depending on which Table you wanna take),

```
db.Table.GroupBy (m => m.EnteredBy)
                .Select(g => g.First()).ToList();
```

**Solution 2**

... just change your view's Model to `@model IEnumerable<string>`

add a ToList() to your query, and change the foreach in your view

```
@foreach (var m in Model)
    {
        @m<br />
    }
```

**General remark**

Don't need a ViewBag for count :

you can use

```
@Model.Count();
```

Comment: Thanks Raphael, I've tried both of those solutions but I'm getting same result that I posted in Dismissile's answer.